# Lync SDK initialized

Tags: lync, lync-client-sdk

I wrote an application that will take a url as a commandline argument and starts a conversation window with directly video mode(Not IM).
Key points are: 
1)It should launch lync client if lync.exe is not running
2)SignIn User if he is not logged in 
3)Launch a call if the user is in SignedIn state

Everything working great but sumtimes i am getting an Exception

When the Lync client(lync.exe) is not running i am starting the process through the application using

```
Process.start("C:\lync.exe")
```

after that i am using

```
Lync.Model.LyncClient.GetClient();
```

Which is throwing "Host Process is not running".

So, In a nutshell i have to wait till the lync client is intialized

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Can you share the approach how you implemented that , our requirement is

We need to develop a website in Asp.net MVC 4 which will connect user within the organisation on Lync or (skype for business now):The ask is:
1) A Sales guy see 10 Technical person in the list which is in database and all of them are in AD if that helps
2) A sales guy click on an icon to connect to a technical person, a lync window appears on client machine (We can assume that all client will have Lync or skype for business up and running on their system from where they will access website)
3) A lync window appears on the machine of a person we are trying to connect to with Default text “hi! Bla Bla Bla”

Can somebody point me to the correct implementation with some set up details from infrastructure POV as well.

Answer (score 0):

Giving a delay may solve your issue.

```
Process.Start("lync.exe");
Thread.Sleep(5000);
```

If you want to avoid the delay one option would be to use UI Suppressed mode.
Lync.Model.LyncClient.GetClient(true); will return a sideByside instance of lync.exe. This instance should be initialized using BeginInitialize() method.